# Solve the following cycloid equation with approximation methode??

Tags: calculus

Solve the  cycloid equation  $\sin^2x-\frac{3}{2}\cos x + q x^2=0$ with Assuming $q$ to be  very small (Ignore the powers of $q$ which are higher than $1$)

here is my method :I consider function $x=x(0)+q x$

well!I haven't solved equations like this before,but I hope someone may help me...I am not sure about the rest of the way....thanks

Comment: Why do you consider function $x=x(0)+qx$??

Answer (score 1):

First you solve $\sin^2 x_0 - \frac 32 \cos x_0=0$ for $x_0$.  Can you do that?  Then you let $x=x_0+\Delta x$, but do not consider the $\Delta x$ in the term with $q$.  This gives $\sin^2(x_0+\Delta x)-\frac 32 \cos (x_0+\Delta x)+qx^2_0=0$  If you expand the trig functions you can get an equation for $\Delta x$, or you can use the Taylor series $\sin^2(x+\Delta x) \approx \Delta x(\sin^2 x)'|_{x=x_0}$ and similarly for the $\cos$ term which gives a linear equation for $\Delta x$